# How to integrate the AWS Cognito built-in UI?

Tags: amazon-cognito, callbackurl

I've been experimenting with Cognito for a few days, and I am now testing the Built-in signing UIs. I have managed to get it working, I am able to see the login page and successfully login with a User I have created. For my callback URL I'm using localhost:3000 as a testing ground, where I'm running a React SPA.

However, I am at a complete loss about what to do once I'm redirected. The documentation says I should get a URL with a JWT as a query parameter. Instead, I'm getting a URL of the form:

`localhost:3000/?code=########-####-####-####-############`

where `#` is an alphanumeric character. I don't recognize this code, I don't think it is a JWT. I would highly appreciated it anyone could:

1. explain what it is
2. direct me to any kind of documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After redirection, You are getting `localhost:3000/?code=########-####-####-####-############`

This means you have enabled [code grant flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html)

**This code is used to get the tokens from Amazon Cognito.**

**Request Type**: POST

**URL**: https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token

**PayLoad**:
`grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&
code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>&
redirect_uri=com.myclientapp://myclient/redirect`

Here you can see we are passing `code` in the payload with redirect url.

The response of this POST request will be your tokens ( If Successful authentication :) )

Sample Response:

```
{
 "access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd",
 "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je",
 "id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r",
 "token_type":"Bearer", 
 "expires_in":3600
}
```

You can save this token in your localstorage or sessionstorage for further custom authentication.

Please refer all the available endpoints of amazon cognito for more details.

Ex: 
[Authorization Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html)
[Token Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)

I hope now it makes clear to you!

Comment: Thank you. I had figured it out, but much appreciated still. Question: I have been unable to make Token authorization work with the built-in UI. Do you know if I have to add anything to the login URL?

Comment: We are doing token authorization in our custom UI application. But you can have a look into the endpoints that are being called from network tab of your browser. Try to check that URL by manually invoking them from PostMan / Advance Rest Client.
Hope this helps!